# Multiple RSA server certificates not allowed

Tags: ubuntu, apache-httpd, ssl, certificates

I purchased a multidomain certificate, and I was trying to install it on my server.

I put the following information inside the virtual host for one of my sites:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
...
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/16478325.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/private.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/16478325.ca-bundle
...
```

I then tried to restart apache, and got a failure, and I was told to check my apache logs.

The error message received was this:

```
Init: Multiple RSA server certificates not allowed
```

I assumed that that meant I had to install an SSL certificate for the entire site, not on one domain.

But that also did not work.

I got the error:

```
Illegal attempt to re-initialise SSL for server (SSLEngine On should go in the VirtualHost, not in global scope.)
```

Why isn't this working? How do I configure my domains to each have SSL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(summary of comments)

You have a conflicting SSL virtual host from the Ubuntu/Debian `default-ssl` virtual host. `a2dissite default-ssl` will fix the immediate problem.

The [Apache HTTP Server Wiki](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/) has a [guide to configuring name-based SSL virtual hosts](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHosts) which you should review. The guide shows them all in one file, but you can split the different `VirtualHost` sections to different files (in `sites-available/`)—they're all included in the main config anyway. You can put stuff like the `NameVirtualHost` line in `ports.conf` or in `conf-available/`. `/usr/share/doc/apache2/README.Debian.gz` contains some documentation on the Debian/Ubuntu apache config handling.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you comment out the boiler plate SSL lines above in the config file.

```
    #SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
    #SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
    #SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl.crt/server-ca.crt
```

I ran into this same problem a moment ago and found your question before I realized it was pilot error on my part.

Otherwise, everything works with multiple certs on the same host (meaning two VirtualHost configurations for port 443 on the same host.